# string concatenation in android studio java

Tags: string-concatenation

I am trying to display invalid user credentials in textview by concatenating the invalid fields.So that i get a textview like invalid name,username,contact...at a time.
  I want the invalid fields to display at a time.

I have declared a string and tried to concatenate but the result is textview displays all the fields even if its valid one.

```
  boolean flag = true;
   String s1,s2,s3,s4,s5;
    boolean checkDataEntered() {
    if (isEmpty(Name)) {
        Name.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.error);
        s1="Full name";
        flag = false;
 }
if (isEmpty(Username)) {
        Username.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.error);
        s2="Username";
        flag = false;
    }
   if (isEmail(EmailId)) {
        EmailId.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.error);
        s3="Email";
        flag = false;
    }
     if (flag) {
        return true;
      } else {
          textView7.setText("Please fill"+s1+ s2+ s3) ;
         return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are concatenating all the fields in your `else` statement.

`textView7.setText("Please fill"+s1+ s2+ s3);`

But your requirement is to concatenate it only if it is empty. So you should try like,

```
boolean flag = true;
String error = "";
boolean checkDataEntered() {
    if (isEmpty(Name)) {
        Name.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.error);
        error += "Full name";
        flag = false;
    }
    if (isEmpty(Username)) {
        Username.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.error);
        error += ",Username";
        flag = false;
    }
    if (isEmail(EmailId)) {
        EmailId.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.error);
        error += ",Email";
        flag = false;
    }
    if (flag) {
        return true;
    } else {
        textView7.setText("Please fill "+error) ;
        return false;
    }
}
```